# Declaring an object as a member variable of itself

Tags: c++, recurrence, class-members

I'm writing a game engine (using SFML libraries) and I can't seem to get this to work. I'm writing the GUI portion of code and I want to declare a object of the same class inside itself (parent/child so I can link objects together). I can't do this unless the class is finished being instantiated. Is there some sort of makeshift way I can force the child and parent variables to somehow work?

```
#ifndef ELEMENT_H
#define ELEMENT_H

#include <iostream>

class Element
{
    public:
        Element();
    private:
        int id, position_x, position_y, pixel_x, pixel_y, width, height;

        Element parent;
        std::vector<Element> child;
};

#endif // ELEMENT_H
```

Error I get:

```
include\Element.h|13|error: field 'parent' has incomplete type 'Element'|
```

Comment: If you could do that, `Element` would have infinite size.

Comment: OOoh, good point.. What if I made them undeclared pointers?

Comment: Does implementation file exist? If it doesn't, you can change parent to be a reference: `Element& parent` and have it initialized in the constructor initialization list.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot declare a set variable of type `Class <x>` within itself like you have there.

You can, however, have a class that contains a data member that is a **pointer** to itself...

```
#ifndef ELEMENT_H
#define ELEMENT_H

#include <iostream>

class Element
{
    public:
        Element();
    private:
        int id, position_x, position_y, pixel_x, pixel_y, width, height;

        Element *parent;
        std::vector<Element *> child;
};

#endif // ELEMENT_H
```

Comment: omfg!! yes! This is what happens when I program late at night xD tyvm

Comment: hahaha glad to help! @Honor

Answer (score 1):

You can make `parent` of type `Element*` (or `std::shared_ptr<Element>` if you want to use the smart pointers feature of c++11/boost)

Can you imagine the problem of having an Element with an Element inside it and an Element inside it? It would never end. Typically chains like this have one Element that is the `root`, where `parent = NULL`.

Comment: omfg thanks so much haha! I wasn't thinking last night x.x